# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of in retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have created an Android Application and trying to update profile with data base.

```
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
         Log.d("TAG", "response: "+response.body().string());

         String result = response.body().string();
         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

         if(jsonObj.has("status")){

         if(jsonObj.get("status").equals("success")){

             Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
             .make(layout, "User details successfully updated",
             Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

             snackbar.show();

     } else {
         Log.d("TAG","CLICK Failed");
         buttonVisible();
     }
```

When i tried to `Log` the response, I am getting `TAG: response: {"status":"success","message":"User details successfully updated."}`
but when i tried to convert `response.body().string();` to `string` I am getting this error`**org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of**` . can you please tell me how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put

```
String result = response.body().string();
```

before

```
Log.d("TAG", "response: "+response.body().string());
```

Such that it looks like

```
String result = response.body().string();
Log.d("TAG", "response: "+result);
```

Just in case someone bumps into the same weird thing as I have. I run my code during development in Debug Mode and apparently since OKHttp 2.4

```
..the response body is a one-shot value that may be consumed only once
```

So when in debug there is a call "behind the scene" from the inspector and the body is always empty. See: http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/Response.html

Comment: Well elaborate.Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `Log` print your string object like :

```
String result = response.body().string();
Log.d("TAG", "response: "+result);
```